# Regarding regular expressions and XML

Tags: python, xml, regex

I have data in XML format. Example is shown as follow. I want to extract data from `<text> tag`. 
Here is my XML data.

```
    <text>
    The 40-Year-Old Virgin is a 2005 American buddy comedy
    film about a middle-aged man's journey to finally have sex.

    <h1>The plot</h1>
    Andy Stitzer (Steve Carell) is the eponymous 40-year-old virgin.
    <h1>Cast</h1>

    <h1>Soundtrack</h1>

    <h1>External Links</h1>
</text>
```

I need only `The 40-Year-Old Virgin is a 2005 American buddy comedy film about a middle-aged man's journey to finally have sex.` Is it possible? thanks

Comment: Don't use regex. Use [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions that are remarkably similar...

Comment: Obligatory XML-regex link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an XML parser to parse XML. Using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content='''\
<text>
    The 40-Year-Old Virgin is a 2005 American buddy comedy
    film about a middle-aged man's journey to finally have sex.

    <h1>The plot</h1>
    Andy Stitzer (Steve Carell) is the eponymous 40-year-old virgin.
    <h1>Cast</h1>

    <h1>Soundtrack</h1>

    <h1>External Links</h1>
</text>
'''

text=ET.fromstring(content)
print(text.text)
```

yields

```
    The 40-Year-Old Virgin is a 2005 American buddy comedy
    film about a middle-aged man's journey to finally have sex.
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expression to parse XML/HTML. Use a proper parser like BeautifulSoup or lxml in python.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you find yourself looking at XML data and thinking about regular expressions, you should stop and ask yourself why you aren't considering a real XML parser. The structure of XML makes it perfectly suited for a proper parser, and maddeningly frustrating for regular expressions.

If you *must* use regular expressions, the following should do. *Until your document changes*!

```
import re
p = re.compile("<text>(.*)<h1>")
p.search(xml_text).group(1)
```

*Spoiler: regular expressions might be appropriate if this is just a one-off problem that needs a quick and dirty solution. Or they  might be appropriate if you know the input data will be fairly static and can't tolerate the overhead of a parser.*

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could do this using [`ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
In [18]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

In [19]: t = et.parse('f.xml')

In [20]: print t.getroot().text.strip()
The 40-Year-Old Virgin is a 2005 American buddy comedy
    film about a middle-aged man's journey to finally have sex.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> data = """<text>
...     The 40-Year-Old Virgin is a 2005 American buddy comedy
...     film about a middle-aged man's journey to finally have sex.
... 
...     <h1>The plot</h1>
...     Andy Stitzer (Steve Carell) is the eponymous 40-year-old virgin.
...     <h1>Cast</h1>
... 
...     <h1>Soundtrack</h1>
... 
...     <h1>External Links</h1>
... </text>"""
>>> xml = ET.XML(data)
>>> xml.text
"\n    The 40-Year-Old Virgin is a 2005 American buddy comedy\n    film about a middle-aged man's journey to finally have sex.\n\n    "
>>> xml.text.strip().replace('\n   ', '')
"The 40-Year-Old Virgin is a 2005 American buddy comedy film about a middle-aged man's journey to finally have sex."
```

And there you go!